# Overriding new SqlParameter

Tags: c#

I need to check the value of the SqlParameter object and change it based on special labels. ie: [BB] ==> Baseball, [FP] ==> Fastpitch.

I can do it with an additional function like this:

```
_params.Add(new SqlParameter("@Change", paramCheck(obj.Change)));
```

I would like to try overriding the new SqlParameter method/function and run my check in there. How can I do that?

Comment: Do the checks before creating the parameter...

Comment: You need some sort of data layer to check what the current value is before creating a new parameter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can't *literally* override `new SqlParameter` because [`SqlParameter` is `sealed`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter(v=vs.110).aspx), but you can create a function that returns a new `SqlParameter`:

```
public SqlParameter NewSqlParameter(string name, object value) 
{
    return new SqlParameter(name, paramCheck(value));
}
```

and call it as such:

```
_params.Add(NewSqlParameter("@Change", obj.Change));
```

Answer (score 2):

How about building an extension method:

```
public static void Add(this SqlParameterCollection parms, SomeType obj)
{
    // do some checks

    // add the parameter
}
```

Usage of this now looks like this:

```
_params.Add(obj);
```

**UPDATE:** as stated by Patrick below, the concern here is how do you add the parameter if it's coming from multiple types. The answer can't be known without knowing *a lot* more about the application itself.

But, an interface may be the answer if the objects share an interface. Reflection may be the answer if they are unknown object. Neither of which are hard to implement. But this extension method gives you the flexibility to encapsulate that implementation.

If you end up having to use reflection, Patrick raised a good concern that you may want to change the name of the method to something like `AddParamWithCheck` because at that point you would be accepting an `object` instead of a well-known type. However, that was not implied to *me* from the question.

Comment: You risk calling the wrong method if the parameters don't match exactly to your extension method. I would suggest to use another name to make very clear which version you call.

Comment: @PatrickHofman have a look at my modification from the original post. The extension method now only accepts the object of the specific custom type.

Comment: @PatrickHofman, care to elaborate? No `Add` is going to accept that custom type. It would result in a build error.

Comment: Where is the value of the parameter? Or the name? What if the value is a string? Do want to create a method for each and every type?

Comment: @PatrickHofman, the code snippet provided works off of the object itself. It's clear that some sort of interface may need to be implemented to create shared code, or even some sort of reflection. But I think the fact that there is an extension method that accepts a custom type allows the OP to operate off of that custom type in any way necessary (e.g. creating that interface).